# Android 4.4; Open Chrome Webapp with Intent

Tags: android, webrtc, google-chrome-app

I am trying to implement a webpage with WebRTC in my app. Since the 4.4 WebView still doesn't support WebRTC, I am trying to find another way to open a webpage in fullscreen in chrome with WebRTC capabilities.

Is there an intent I can use to open Chrome in "WebApp"-mode?

Comment: Try using "browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {}" Read about that, maybe it working

Comment: Already tried that, without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);
```

MyWebClient.java

```
public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    /**
     * Notify the host application that a page has started loading.
     */
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.
     */
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        // startActivity(intent);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Notify the host application that a page has finished loading.
     */
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

Comment: This just uses the Android 4.4 WebView, which does not support WebRTC; https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview